# embed block anywhere fails at drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

It's been a week I have played around with drupal 7. With drupal 6, I used to be able to place (login) block anywhere with this:

```
  $block = (object) module_invoke($module, 'block', 'view', $delta);
  $block->module = $module;
  $block->delta = $delta;
  return theme('block', $block);
```

or this:

```
$block = module_invoke('user', 'block', 'view', 0); 
$vars['login'] = $block['content'];
```

I changed the delta '0' for Drupal 7:

```
$block = module_invoke('user', 'block', 'view', 'login'); // I have changed from 0 to 'login' for delta at drupal 7
$vars['login'] = $block['content'];
```

Both result in Fatal error. Any change that I am not aware of with module_invoke? There is no specific change at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke/7

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hook_block($op) was changed to hook_block_op() in Drupal 7. Try:

```
$block = module_invoke('user', 'block_view', 'login');
$vars['login'] = $block['content'];
```

Or why not use the form directly:

```
$vars['login'] = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
```

Comment: Thanks. I know somebody knew it. Only need to use "render" or "drupal_render" to make it work, otherwise I get an empty Array. Do you know which to use in this case, "render" or "drupal_render"? Thanks again

Comment: Ah, use render() by default in D7.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7 keeps all objects now in render arrays until the last output, this allows for a greater degree of control over content. In which case to get a final output use the render() function. Simples.

```
   <?php
              $block = module_invoke('user', 'block_view', 'login');
              print render($block); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better solution, which respects Drupal theming.

```
function block_render($module, $block_id) {
  $block = block_load($module, $block_id);
  $block_content = _block_render_blocks(array($block));
  $build = _block_get_renderable_array($block_content);
  $block_rendered = drupal_render($build);
  return $block_rendered;
}
```